# Pcap link type of Infiniband

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap, infiniband

I'm Trying to capture Infiniband packets using the pcap format, and for that i thought i should use  **`LINKTYPE_INFINIBAND  247   DLT_INFINIBAND`** as mentioned in the [tcpdump's LINK-LAYER HEADER TYPES](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html).
When i try to open the pcap file in Wireshark i get this error message -

> The file "ib.pcap" is a capture for a network type that Wireshark doesn't support.
>   (pcap: **network type 247 unknown or unsupported**)

Moreover, in [wireshark sample captures - InfiniBand](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#InfiniBand) the sample is  -

> File infiniband.pcap (8.7KB)
>   Description A libpcap trace file of low level InfiniBand **frames in DLT_ERF format**.

So, why DLT_INFINIBAND (247) is not recognized by wireshark, and why the sample uses DLT_ERF (197)?

Thanks!

Comment: Both `tcpdump` and `wireshark` should use `libpcap` to write out the `pcap` files.  Did you force `tcpdump` to use `LINKTYPE_INFINIBAND`? Infiniband boards are expensive and it might be that the developers of wireshark and/or libpcap did not had the resources to test them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the answers to the questions above is in - 
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/7454/